# Native Javascript Selections

Tags: javascript

I need to use native Javascript and for some of these I need to select more than one attribute (ex. a div with a class and id). Here is a code sample of what I've got so far. The example has all single selections.

```
    var $ = function (selector) {
var elements = [];

var doc = document, i = doc.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    iTwo = doc.getElementById("some_id"), // #some_id
    iThree = doc.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    // ^ Lets say I wanted to select an input with ID name as well. Should it not be doc.getElementsByTagName("input").getElementById("idname")
    iFour = doc.getElementsByClassName("some_class"); // some_class

elements.push(i,iTwo,iThree,iFour);

return elements;
    };
```

Oh yes, I forgot to mention I cannot use querySelector at all...

Comment: `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`

Comment: ^^ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: you can use [querySelector/querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), which allows you to use css selectors. But note the browser compatibility at the bottom.

Comment: ^^ Basically, does not work in IE < 8

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention I cannot use querySelector at all...

Comment: @Kald the reason `querySelector` was not added before IE8 is that it is not really required beyond the bootstrapping stage of the application. Build your JavaScript wiring to the DOM once and then use object references

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the properties you want to select on. For example, you might pass an object like:

```
{tagname: 'div', class: 'foo'};
```

and the function might be like:

```
function listToArray(x) {
  for (var result=[], i=0, iLen=x.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      result[i] = x[i];
  }
  return result;
}

function getByProperties(props) {
  var el, elements;
  var baseProps = {id:'id', tagName:'tagName'};
  var result = [];

  if ('tagName' in props) {
    elements = listToArray(document.getElementsByTagName(props.tagName));

  } else if ('id' in props) {
    elements = [document.getElementById(props.id)];
  }

  for (var j=0, jLen=elements.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    el = elements[j];
    for (var prop in props) {

      // Include all with tagName as used above. Avoids case sensitivity
      if (prop == 'tagName' || (props.hasOwnProperty(prop) && props[prop] == el[prop])) {
        result.push(el);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// e.g.
getByProperties({tagName:'div', className:'foo'});
```

However it's a simplistic approach, it won't do things like child or nth selectors.

You can perhaps look at someone else's selector function (there are a few around) and follow the fork to support non–qSA browsers. These are generally based on using a regular expression to tokenise a selector, then apply the selector manually similar to the above but more extensivly.

They also allow for case sensitivity for values (e.g. tagName value) and property names to some extent, as well as map HTML attribute names to DOM property names where required (e.g. class -> className, for -> htmlFor, etc.).